# Delayed request for open graph permissions.

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have an app which never requested for open graph permission to post to the wall.
But now I am in the process of integrating open graph and realized that I need to request `publish actions`.

[image]

Now if I add the `public actions` permissions to the app, how does facebook request it from existing users who approved without this perm?

Answer (score 5):

when your existing user returns, it will ask for just `publish_actions` permission if rest of the required permission he has already given.